# How to encode poker cards?

Tags: deep-learning, encoding, reinforcement-learning

I am currently working on a poker AI and I am stuck on this question: What is the best way to encode poker cards for my AI? I am using deep reinforcement learning techniques and I just don't know how to anwser my question.

The card information is stored as a string. For example: "3H" would be "three of hearts". I thought about ranking the cards and then attaching values to them such that a high-rated card like AH ("Ace of hearts") would get a high number like 52 or something like that. The problem with this approach is that it doesn't take the suits into acccount.

I have seen some methods where they just assign a number to each and every card such that at the end there are 52 numbers from 0-51 (https://www.codewars.com/kata/52ebe4608567ade7d700044a/javascript). The problem I see with that is that my neural net wouldn't or at least have difficulties getting the connection between similar cards like Aces ('cause as in the link above one Ace is labeled with a 0 the other one with 13 etc.).

Can someone please help me with this question such that the encodings take care of the: suits, values, ranks, etc and my NN would be able to get the connections between similar cards.

Thanks in andvance

Comment: Why not do a card embedding vector with a one-hot for the suit and an extra dimension for the card rank? I think that would accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks! But I also want to pass some more information to my model (table cards, # of players, position, last raised amount, own stack, etc.). Do you maybe know how I could accomplish this ('cause the input tensor to my model should have a specific shape and having all those different info's is kinda hard to implement)? My bad for not inculding this in the main question